# Dask Grouby Performance for nunique is too slow. How to improve the performance?

Tags: pandas, dask

I have large files of size more than 5GB. I have stored them in parquet format. When I do groupby operation as shown below code for small sample set of 600k+ records, Dask is taking more than 6 mins, whereas pandas took only 0.4 seconds. Though I understand pandas is faster if the dataset fits in memory, my question is if I pass entire parquet file to Dask dataframe, will performance improve?

Also suggest me how to improve the below code, so that i can run in few seconds rather than in minutes.

Example: Using Dask Dataframe

```
StartTime = datetime.datetime.now()
df = dd.read_parquet('201908.parquet', columns=['A', 'B'], engine='pyarrow')
print (len(df))
df = df.set_index ('A')
rs = df.groupby('A').B.nunique().nlargest(10).compute(scheduler='processes')
print (rs)
EndTime = datetime.datetime.now()
print ("Total Time Taken for processing: " + str(EndTime - StartTime))
```

Output is:

```
606995
A
-3868378286825833950    7
 1230391617280615928    7
 381683316762598393     6
-5730635895723403090    5
 903278193888929465     5
 2861437302225712286    5
-9057855329515864244    4
-8963355998258854688    4
-7876321060385968364    4
-6825439721748529898    4
Name: B, dtype: int64
Total Time Taken for processing: 0:06:05.042146
```

Example using Pandas:

```
StartTime = datetime.datetime.now()
df = pd.read_parquet('201908.parquet', columns=['A', 'B'], engine='pyarrow')
print (len(df))
df = df.set_index ('A')
rs = df.groupby('A').B.nunique().nlargest(10)
print (rs)
EndTime = datetime.datetime.now()
print ("Total Time Taken for processing: " + str(EndTime - StartTime))
```

Output is:

```
606995
A
-3868378286825833950    7
 1230391617280615928    7
 381683316762598393     6
-5730635895723403090    5
 903278193888929465     5
 2861437302225712286    5
-9057855329515864244    4
-8963355998258854688    4
-7876321060385968364    4
-6825439721748529898    4
Name: B, dtype: int64
Total Time Taken for processing: 0:00:00.419033
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is an open issue for an approximate groupby nunique algorithm for dask dataframe.  You might look into that if you're particularly interested.  Dask dataframe's non-groupby nunique algorithm is quite a bit faster.

Comment: Hi, I am mainly interested in SeriesGroupby nunique. I tested non-groupby for 160M records. Its quite fast. Happy with that. But this is not useful for my use case. I need groupby unique. Any idea when this issue will be resolved?

Comment: Whenever someone works on it.  Dask is a free open source project.  Progress happens as people work on things.  If you want something done, the best way may be to do it yourself.  If you have time to contribute here, I suspect that others would find this valuable as well.

Comment: Sure, I shall contribute as much as I can. Please let me know how shall i work on this.

Comment: Hi Rocklin, i would like to know if anyone worked in this issue? Or is there any alternate solution available for nunique option?